# React: Is there a way to access component state from function in another file?

Tags: reactjs

I've a react component which includes a large function that updates the component state, the function is large so I want to move it to a separate file and export it in the react component. But I don't find anyway to access the component state if I move the function to its own file.

Is there anyway to do this ?

example:

component.tsx

```
import { myFunction } from './function.ts'
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)
const my_component = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={myFunction}>Run function</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default my_component
```

function.ts

```
export const myFunction = () => {
  // do something that updates `toggle`
}
```

Comment: Please add some code for the better understanding.

Comment: Any chance you can use hooks? https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: @LuisSardon I'm already using hooks, but the thing is I want to extract the function to another file, and import it in the react component. When I extract the function to a new file I don't have access to the component state, this is what I'm trying to solve

Comment: Isn't this the problem [`redux`](https://redux.js.org/) is meant to solve?

Comment: @LuisSardon check the updated post

Comment: @lgflorentino I have only one component, and the function isn't in another component, it's just a function in a separate file.

Comment: @AymanTarig I don't understand what you mean by "the function", you can have a custom state hook https://dev.to/spukas/react-hooks-creating-custom-state-hook-300c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do the logic apart from the component and return the result to the component. have a look at the code below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-dubinsky-930p7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I like that, this way he didn't have to change too much of his code... just by doing `onClick={() => setToggle(myFunction(toggle))}`

Answer (score 1):

This is just a raw example of what you can do with custom state hooks (reference: https://dev.to/spukas/react-hooks-creating-custom-state-hook-300c)

```
import React from 'react';

export function useMyFunction(value) {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = React.useState(value || false);
  
  const myFunction = () => {
    // do something that updates `toggle` with setToggle(...)
  }

  return { toggle, myFunction };
}
```

```
import { useMyFunction } from './function.ts'

const my_component = () => {
  const [toggle, myFunction] = useMyFunction(false)

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={myFunction}>Run function</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default my_component
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by 2 different ways one using HOC components and another just by using functions.

Approach 1: Using HOC

handler.js

```
const withHandlers = (WrappedComponent) => {
    class HandlerComponent extends Component {
      state = {toggle:false};

      myFunction = () => {
        //Do your update here
      }

      render() {
        return <WrappedComponent 
          toggle={this.state.toggle
          myFunction={this.myFunction}
        />
     }
};
```

my_component.js

```
const my_component = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={props.myFunction}>Run function</button>
    </div>
}

export default withHandlers(my_component);
```

Approach 2: Using Functions

handler.js

```
export const myFunction(toggle) => {
   return !toggle; //return the changed value
}
```

my_component.js

```
const my_component = () => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
  const myFunction = () => {
    setToggle(handler.myFunction); //the state will be passed as a parameter by default
  };

  return(
    <div>
      <button onClick={myFunction}>Run function</button>
    </div>
);
```

};

Answer (score -1):

For the toggle to work, it must be passed to the function as a props then for update it used state management (redux or react context).

The best solution is to define the toggle in the function itself and pass it a Boolean props to control it.

```
import { myFunction } from './function.ts'
const my_component = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={myFunction(false)}>Run function</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default my_component
```

function.ts

```
export const myFunction = (props) => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(props || false);
  // your codes
};
```

Comment: I downvoted this answer for two reasons:
1. Your code isn't well written, please fix this part `onClick={myFunction toggle="false"}`
2. I don't understand why you would use useState on an event handler